# JAVAX @GET Annotation

Tags: java

I am trying to get an ID from an url and, possibly the page and limit. What I currently have doesn't work and I am not seeing what I am doing wrong. Here is what I currently have.

```
    @GET
    @Path("venue/{locationid}?limit={limit}&page={page}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=utf-8")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=utf-8")
    public String locationDetail(@PathParam("locationid") String locationid,@QueryParam("limit") @DefaultValue("10") String limit,@QueryParam("page") @DefaultValue("1") String page ) throws IOException {
        return service.locationDetail(locationid,limit,page);   
    }

}
```

The locationid is required, the other two are not really required and have to be their default values when not given. However when I look at the console I get the following error.

> failed to execute: javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: Could not find
>   resource for full path: ./venue/175?limit=1&page=1

Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: What JAX-RS implementation do you use?

Comment: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.ws.rs

Comment: It's specification. I'm asking about implementation. Is it RESTeasy, Jersey, Apache CXF or something else?